# my tkinter window appears after I have ended the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi4

I am making a weather station using a raspberry pi and I am trying to use a tkinter window to display the data, however, the window only appears after I have used ctrl + c to end the program. I am using the terminal to run the code (the command is sudo python test.py)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
from WeatherPiHumiture import *
from WeatherPiBarometer import *
import Tkinter as tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

def main():
    while True:
                result = read_dht11_dat()
                if result:
                        humidity, temperature = result
                        humid = "Humidity: %s %% " % (humidity)
                        humids = tkinter.Label(
                            text=humid,
                            fg='black',
                            bg='white',
                            height=2,
                            width=40
                        )

                #Barometer
                sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
                temp = sensor.read_temperature()    # Read temperature to veriable temp
                pressure = sensor.read_pressure()
                
                temperatures = 'Temperature: {0:0.2f} C'.format(temp)# Print temperature
                temperate = tkinter.Label(
                        text=temperatures,
                        fg='black',
                        bg='white',
                        height=2,
                        width=40
                )
            
                pressure = '{0:0.2f}'.format(pressure)
                pressure = float(pressure)
                millibar = pressure / 100
                millibar = str(millibar)
                pressured = 'Pressure: ' + millibar + ' MilliBar'
                pressures = tkinter.Label(
                        text=pressured,
                        fg='black',
                        bg='white',
                        height=2,
                        width=40
                )

                temperate.grid(row=0, column=0)
                pressures.grid(row=0, column=1)
                humids.grid(row=0, column=2)
                
                time.sleep(1)

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        destroy()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: why do you def main? its not c++ xD

Comment: @Evorage: creating a `main` function is pretty common, even in python.

Comment: Try passing parent window to the label as parent. For example tkinter.Label(window, then other args)

Comment: @tan_an is this what you meant `humids = tkinter.Label(
master=window.mainloop(),
text=humid,
fg='black',
bg='white',
height=2,
width=40
)`

Comment: Its should be humids=tkinter.Label(window, text=humid, fg='black',  bg='white'). This will add the label inside window which you have created at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Add `window.mainloop()` to your `try` block

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
        window.mainloop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        destroy()
        window.destroy()
```